# CSS broken on Django admin on developer server

Tags: css, django, django-admin

I'm getting some really weird issues with the Django admin application. I'm running everything on the `manage.py runserver` development server, so I can't imagine what the issue would be, but I'm seeing something like this:

[image]

Obviously, this isn't ideal, so I'd like to return it to actually looking good. I'm using the `staticfiles` app, which I think might be a part of the problem, but I don't know for sure. What am I doing wrong here?

The admin site seems to link to the following CSS sheets, which aren't being found:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/base.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/dashboard.css" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean you're using the staticfiles contrib package in Django 1.3. If that's correct, you only need:

```
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL+'admin/'
```

Comment: That did it. I am indeed using the `staticfiles` contrib package, and this fixes it for sure.

Answer (score 2):

In `settings.py` uncomment(if commented) or add `'django.contrib.staticfiles',` and restart the server.
This should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably got your `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` set incorrectly.

Try setting it to:

```
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = "/admin-media/"
```

And see if that fixes everything.

Ok, three more things to check:

1. Just a sanity check: are the admin stylesheets which are 404ing actually prefixed with `/admin-media/`?
2. Is there any chance that your custom URL handlers are matching? (ex, do you have something like `url(r'^admin-media/', …)` in your root `urls.py`?
3. It's unlikely, but is there any chance your Django install could be broken? do the `.css` files actually exist in `…/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin`?

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help. I'm still getting 404s on the stylesheets.

Comment: Dang, that usually does it for me. A couple more things to check then; see my edit.